# How could I find specific texts in one column of another dataset? Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataset

I have 2 datasets. One contains a column of companies name, and another contains a column of headlines of news. So the aim I want to achieve is to find all the news whose headline contains one  company in the other datasets.[Basically the two datasets are like this, and I wanna select the news with specific company names](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQs0d.png)

I have tried to use for loop to achieve my goals, but I think it takes too much time and I think pandas or some other libraries can do this in an easier way.

I am a starter in python.

Comment: Can you share a reproducible example of your two dataframes (`!= images`) and the exact expected output ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you should have 2 data sets with different columns, first, you need to loop through the dataset that contains the company name to search in the headline, then you could use *obj. find(“search”)* to find matches in both datasets.
Also if every query is stored in a CSV format you could use the *split()* function to get the only column you wanna use

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that you have saved your company names in a `pd.Series` called `company` and headlines and texts in a `pd.DataFrame` called `df`, this will be what you are looking for:

```
# it will add a column called "company" to your initial df
for org, headline in zip(company, df['headline']):
    if org in headline:
        df.loc[df['headline'] == headline, 'company'] = org
```

You should pay attention to lower and upper case letters, as this will only find the corresponding company if the exact same word appears in the headline.